# Rails - Adding a "Delete" button to a Users Timetable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I have a rails App where Users can have a timetable with a one to many relationship.

When i add this

```
<%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

to _user.html it renders a delete link which deletes a user no problem

but when i add this

```
<%= link_to "delete", timetable, method: :delete,
                    data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

to _timetable.html.erb it throws an error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/timetable.4"):
```

My Routes.rb

```
  get 'password_resets/new'
  get 'password_resets/edit'
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'timetable' => 'timetables#new'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'mobile' => 'users#mobile'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'


  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :timetables
  resources :users
  resources :projects
```

Timetable Controller

```
 class TimetablesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def index
    @timetables = current_user.timetables.find(current_user)
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @timetable = Timetable.new
    @timetables = @user.timetables.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 1)
  end

  def feed
    Timetable.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end

  def show
    @feed_items3 = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @timetable = current_user.timetables.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @timetable = Timetable.new(timetable_params)
    @user = User.find(current_user)

    if current_user.timetables.create(timetable_params)
      flash[:success] = "Timetable created!"
      redirect_to timetable_path
    else
      flash[:success] = "Timetable not created!"
      redirect_to timetable_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @timetable = Timetable.find(params[:id])
    @timetable.destroy
    redirect_to timetables_path, notice:  "The timetable #{@timetable.name} has been deleted."
  end

  private
  def timetable_params
    params.require(:timetable).permit(:name, :attachment, :id)
  end

  def correct_user
    @project = current_user.projects.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @project.nil?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your Controllers it is hard to be sure, but I would look at a few areas:

Specifying the path & the timetable object to be deleted:

```
 <%= link_to "Delete Timetable", timetable_path(timetable), :method => :delete %>
```

---

Ensure that the destroy action for the timetable sits within the timetable_controller

---

Regarding your routes.rb file I am not sure why you need:

`get 'timetable' => 'timetables#new'`

and then also

`resources :timetables`

This is duplication - why not try use 'only' (edit to your preference):

```
resources :timetables, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
```

---